# React state keep old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some issue in React that seems to keep last or old state. 
I have a parent component called MyLists.js that contain a loop function where I rendered child component called Item.js

```
{
     this.state.listProducts.map(d =>
     <Item data={d} /> 
)}
```

And in my Item.js component I set state in constructor :

```
this.state = { showFullDescription: false }
```

The variable "showFullDescription" allows me to see the entire description of a product. Now I have for example 2 products and all states "showFullDescription" are set to false so :

- Product 1 => (showFullDescription = false)
- Product 2 => (showFullDescription = false)
  Next, I show full description for Product 2 by clicking a button and I set state to true so Product 2 => (showFullDescription = true)

The problem is when I add another product, let's call it "Product 3", the full description of "Product 3" is directly shown and for "Product 2" it is hidden. It seems that last state is reflected on "Product 3".
I am really sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Here is full source code : 
**MyLists.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductService from '../../../../services/ProductService';
import Item from './Item';


class MyLists extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
        this.state = {
            products: []
        } 

        this.productService = new ProductService();  
        this.productService.getAllProducts().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                products: res
            })
        }); 
    }

    addProduct(data){
        this.productService.addProduct(data).then((res) => {
            var arr = this.state.products;
            arr.push(res);
            this.setState({
                products: arr
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.products.map(d =>
                    <Item data={d} /> 
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyLists;
```

**Item.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Truncate from 'react-truncate';


class Item extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
        this.state = {
            showFullDescription: false
        } 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
                {
                    !this.state.showFullDescription &&
                    <Truncate lines={10} ellipsis={<a className="btn btn-primary read-more-btn" onClick={() => this.setState({showFullDescription: true})}>Show More</a>}>
                        {this.props.data.description}
                    </Truncate> 
                )}
                {
                    this.state.showFullDescription &&
                    <span>
                        {this.props.data.description}
                    </span>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: Can you post your full code please..

Comment: @Colin is right, please provide your full code...

Comment: @Colin yes sorry, I have update my question and add full code

Comment: Where is ProductService()?

Comment: Add && after !this.state.showFullDescription. The code after && will only render if the condition given evaluates to true...

Comment: @BilalKazmi ProductService is just a service that contains all post and get request to expressJs and save it to database. I have added && in my code but it's still not work unfortunately, bug still there

Comment: What happens on clicking? You don't see description of your first item? maybe because the map function has iterated over it and it moves to next....

Comment: The fact is, you are mapping the products array (or object I don't know) in the first component and your state is in the items component. When the state of items component resets, only this component re-renders and not the first component, at the mean time first component iterates over to next product..

Comment: @BilalKazmi ok I understood, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Welcome.,.......

Comment: @BilalKazmi So how can I proceed to do it well?

Comment: try mapping in the second component....

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax problems and missing `&&` for `!this.state.showFullDescription`.
I've slightly changed the component and use ternary operator to render conditionally. It is a little bit ugly right now, the logic can be written outside of the render. Also, I suggest you to use a linter if you are not using.

**MyLists.js**

```
class MyLists extends React.Component {
    state = {
      products: [
        { id: 1, description: "Foooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo", title: "first" },
        { id: 2, description: "Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrr", title: "second" },
        { id: 3, description: "Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz", title: "third" },
      ]
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.products.map(d =>
            <Item data={d} />
          )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Item.js**

```
class Item extends React.Component {
    state = {
      showFullDescription: false,
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
        { !this.state.showFullDescription
        ?
        <Truncate lines={3} ellipsis={<span>... <button onClick={() => this.setState({showFullDescription: true})}>Read More</button></span>}>
          {this.props.data.description}
        </Truncate>
        :
          <span>
            {this.props.data.description}
          </span>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x24r7k3r9p

Answer (score 0):

You should try mapping in the second component as:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
   state = {
    showFullDescription: false,
   }

render() {
   return (
    <div>
     {this.props..data.map(data=>
      <h2>{this.props.data.title}</h2>
      { !this.state.showFullDescription
      ?
      <Truncate lines={3} ellipsis={<span>... <button onClick={() => 
    this.setState({showFullDescription: true})}>Read More</button> 
    </span>}>
      {this.props.data.description}
    </Truncate>
      :
      <span>
        {this.props.data.description}
      </span>)}
    }
  </div>
   )
  }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have a 'key' property (with unique value) in 'Item' - No warnings about it in console?

Comment: I have changed the line for loop to
{
                    this.state.products.map((d, i) =>
                    <Item data={d} key={i} /> 
                )}
the issue still there

Comment: Yes no warnings in console

Comment: this!=this?  .bind(this) onclick handler? it's described on react docs

Comment: use keys, really  ;)

https://codesandbox.io/s/q8975r0n86 - there you have 2 kinds of binding handlers